# Dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04.3: safely convert BIOS Ubuntu installation to UEFI

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I've successfully installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 64-bit on my MSI GE62-2QF ([full specs here](http://www.canadacomputers.com/product_info.php?cPath=1198&item_id=087187)). As with the norm these days, the laptop came with Windows 10 pre-installed.

I followed the instructions as usual, but `grub` does not show up when the laptop is booted. I suspect this is because the laptop is in `UEFI` mode, and Ubuntu was installed (accidentally) as `legacy`.

I'm able to boot into `grub` if I switch the firmware to use `legacy` mode, and prioritize the Ubuntu partition when booting. But I want to use `grub` correctly for both Windows 10 and Ubuntu!

How do I get `grub` to work as usual? I understand I need to convert my Ubuntu installation to `UEFI`, and that I can use `boot-repair` to do the conversion. But here are my concerns:

- I want to use `grub` as my primary bootloader into both Windows 10 and Ubuntu (i.e. I want to be able to boot into either OS using `grub`).
- Can I use `boot-repair` to sort this all out without having to use a separate LiveUSB session? Can I just run `boot-repair` on my current local Ubuntu installation to do all of this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All Boot-Repair is doing is uninstalling grub-PC(BIOS) and installing grub-efi-amd64. You can do that yourself, just make sure Internet is working and still best to have live installer in case grub does not install correctly. Some UEFI also need work arounds to boot ubuntu entry, and Windows fast start up must be off. Grub also will not boot Windows with secure boot on.

Comment: @oldfred yes I understand that. But how do I do this? I need specific instructions / step-by-step guide. Also, if this is something that's risky to do, then I'd rather leave it as it is currently. All I need to do is press `F11` on the keyboard and select the `ubuntu` partition to boot into Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, you must install an EFI-mode boot loader for Linux. There are two approaches to doing this that are relatively easy and likely to produce results reasonably reliably, although neither is 100% guaranteed to work:

- Boot an Ubuntu installer *in EFI mode* and select the "try before installing" option. You can then run Boot Repair, which should detect the EFI-mode installation and install an EFI-mode version of GRUB. This approach will use GRUB, which is what you say you want; however, it's something of a leap of faith -- if Boot Repair gets it wrong, the situation might not improve, or might even get worse. Such errors are rare but they do occur from time to time.
- Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) prepare a boot medium, and boot it. (You may need to disable Secure Boot, at least temporarily.) With any luck, rEFInd will enable you to boot both Windows and Ubuntu. If so, boot into Ubuntu and install rEFInd to your hard disk using the rEFInd PPA or Debian package. This approach has the advantage of being more incremental and lower in risk than the Boot Repair approach. It uses rEFInd as its end state rather than GRUB, which is not what you specified -- but I'm not sure if that's because you're a GRUB fan or if you just specified GRUB because that's the Ubuntu default.

There are other ways to achieve the end state of being able to easily boot either OS in EFI mode; in fact, I've written [a whole Web page on the options.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/index.html) Those two are the easiest to set up, though. The other options require more effort to set up initially and/or more ongoing maintenance effort.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How risky is it exactly? To be honest, I don't really mind leaving it as it is currently. All I need to do is press `F11` on the keyboard and select the `ubuntu` partition to boot into Ubuntu.

Comment: Using Boot Repair will *probably* work, but that's not certain. If it doesn't work, it *is* possible to repair it, but doing so will require either following the rEFInd procedure or a lot of expertise (or hand-holding). The rEFInd procedure is much less risky, since testing with an external rEFInd medium makes no changes to your hard disk; and rEFInd installed on your hard disk works just like rEFInd booted from an external drive, so if it works from the external drive, it's virtually certain to work from a hard disk. I can't put precise probabilities on the risk of either approach.

Comment: I understand. I will look into the `rEFInd` approach. Thanks again for the explanation!

Answer (score -1):

UEFI is how the BIOS is set up, in most of my installations on newer systems I need to switch the BIOS to legacy to allow me to change the operating systems from USB or disc. 
You said you were able to get to Ubuntu by changing the BIOS settings. Once in Ubuntu run this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This updates grub to recognized the Windows 10 partition and should allow you to change back to normal boot. Optimally you should be able to run the command, restart the system and get put into grub with your two boot options. If it works, restart and change back to UEFI. Things should stay as they were. Goodluck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Hopefully this works since this is probably the least invasive way. Gonna try it soon and report back!

Comment: Modern computers ship with EFI firmware, *not* BIOS firmware. I know many people and even manufacturers apply the term "BIOS" to EFI firmware, but that's misleading. An EFI is *fundamentally* different from a BIOS. EFI-based computers can boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode by using a sort of BIOS emulator. Running `sudo update-grub` in a BIOS-mode boot of Ubuntu will not convert Ubuntu to boot in EFI mode; you must install an EFI-mode boot loader to do that.

Comment: @Bradley_Taniguchi, yeah unfortunately (now that I think about it) this isn't enough, it only updates the list of entries in `grub`. @Rod_Smith is right.